# Away3d - Object3D won't update

Tags: rotation, transformation, away3d

I'm using Away3D 3.6 and I'm loading a .OBJ file and assigning it to an Object3D object.

e.g.

```
var obj:Object3D = Obj.parse( objData );
obj.rotationY = 35;
view.render(); // this renders the object with a 35º rotation

// (time lapse code)
obj.rotationY = 90;
view.render(); // this does not render the object with a 90º rotation, why??
```

There is a time lapse between the time that I apply a 35º rotation and the time that I apply a 90º rotation, but only the first is rendered.  Why?

It works fine if I set obj = new Cube();

Answer (score 0):

Add an event listener

> addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, _handleEnterFrame);

Then in the _handleEnterFrame function try this:

> private function _handleEnterFrame(ev : Event) : void
>   {
>     obj.rotationY += 1;
>     _view.render();
>   }

Works for me.